# Blur UIImageView with gradient alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

How would I make an `UIImageView` have a gradient blurred `background`? In other words, the image is fully `blurred` on the left and it gets less blurred on the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we did the same in a proyect! we used this method:

```
(UIImage *)blurImage:(CGImageRef*)image withBlurLevel:(CGFloat)blur
{
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"
                                  keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, inputImage, @"inputRadius", @(blur), nil];

    CIImage *outputImage = filter.outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CGImageRef outImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                        fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outImage];

    CGImageRelease(outImage);

    return returnImage;
}
```

This code use your GPU to make the blur, but you need to call that method in another thread if you don't want your UI to be blocked for a second.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that does a good blur, but not the gradient..? Is there a way to add a gradient?

Comment: Probably you can use CGGradient http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html

I never used it, but it seems like a good solution using Core Graphics framework